# Battery is getting drained very fast and laptop is shutting down

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery

I am using Toshiba Satellite L755 with Windows 7 operating system and today it happened that my laptop automatically shuts down few times after  5-20 min of work. I start figuring out what is happening and I observed that battery is draining too fast, even when it is charging. So at the end, my battery level is 0%, battery is charging, but my laptop is shutting down. This is probably battery issue, but why problem remains present when laptop is connected to AC. I thought that this will be source of power, and state of a battery is not an issue (or this should be somehow enabled from windows). Can you help me how to debug this issue?

Edit: From error report:

```
Errors:
USB Suspend:USB Device not Entering Suspend
Platform Power Management Capabilities:PCI Express Active-State Power Management (ASPM) Disabled

Warnings:
Platform Timer Resolution:Platform Timer Resolution
Platform Timer Resolution:Outstanding Timer Request
Power Policy:802.11 Radio Power Policy is Maximum Performance (Plugged In)
```

Comment: At the command prompt, type 'powercfg -energy' 
The evaluation will complete in 60 seconds. When it has finished, an HTML report file that is named 'energy-report.html' will be generated in the current path. Post the errors

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976034/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-you

Comment: Here is link to a file http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/705697/energy-report.html. Is it ok to put it like this?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a faulty cell in your battery.  This is causing your system to consume more power then the power supply can provide (ie the battery is demanding too much of the power to try and charge), and is thus eventually causing your computer to switch off.

You would be better off disconnecting the battery altogether in this case. (and getting a replacement battery if viable)

Comment: Can I work without using battery? To connect laptop to AC?

Comment: Yes. You connect laptop to mains. Just remember to save your work more frequently as you don't have backup if there is a power outage.